# Make subgraph calculated just once in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am building a deep learning model with Tensorflow. Before training, I do some calculation like back propagation. But it is only need to be calculated once. Below is my pseudocode:

```
class residual_net()
    def pseudo_bp(self):
        # do something...
        self.bp = ...

    def build_net(self):
        # build a residual_network....
        # utilize the variable in pseudo_bp
        rn.output = func(self.bp)

def run():
    rn = residual_net()
    rn.pseudo_bp()
    rn.deep_residual_network()
    sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    for i in range(1000):
        err = tf.reduce_mean(rn.output, labels)
        train = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(err)
        sess.run(train, feed_dict=train_feed_dict)
```

I wonder if `pseudo_bp` will run in each iteration? If yes, how can I make it just run once? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
The newest error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 124, in <module>
    sess.run(pseudo_bp, feed_dict=feed_dict)
  File "/Users/yobichi/bigdata/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 717, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/Users/yobichi/bigdata/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 902, in _run
    fetch_handler = _FetchHandler(self._graph, fetches, feed_dict_string)
  File "/Users/yobichi/bigdata/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 358, in __init__
    self._fetch_mapper = _FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetches)
  File "/Users/yobichi/bigdata/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 178, in for_fetch
    (fetch, type(fetch)))
TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type <class 'NoneType'>
```

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

In TensorFlow, you begin by building a [`tf.Graph`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/framework.html#Graph). This graph consists of variables, operations and placeholders. You then begin a [`tf.Session()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/client.html#Session) where you can execute operations and update variables.

In this case, I presume `psuedo_bp` eventually needs you to calculate some operation (like `tf.matmul`). `sess` is like a pointer which will execute various [`tf.Operation`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/framework.html#Operation) whenever you run `sess.run(op)`. You provide some inputs to fill in the placeholders (`feed_dict`).

Hence you will execute `sess.run(op)` only for the first iteration of your for loop. Here is the resulting code -

```
class residual_net()
    def pseudo_bp(self):
        # do something...
        return op

    def build_net(self):
        # build a residual_network....
        rn.output = sth

def run():
    rn = residual_net()
    operation = rn.pseudo_bp()
    rn.build_net()
    err = tf.reduce_mean(rn.output, labels)
    train = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(err)
    # Graph has been built completely. Begin tf.Session()
    sess = tf.Session()
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    for i in range(1000):
        # Carry out the training in each iteration
        # Note that train is an operation here
        sess.run(train, feed_dict=feed_dict)
        if i == 0:
            # Execute `operation` for the first iteration
            result = sess.run(operation, feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry that I have missed a very significant information in my original question. The variable calculated in `pseudo_bp` will be used in `build_net`. And the `build_net` is also linkaged to `train` operation. So I wonder if the `pseudo_bp` will still be operated in the following iteration?

Comment: And I did what you suggest, I got an error, I updated the question for more log information already. Could you please take a look? Thanks!

Comment: What have you assigned `pseudo_bp` to? You probably need to assign it to `rn.bp`

Comment: Assign some value to rn.bp

Comment: No, but are you passing a function into `sess.run()`? You should return a TensorFlow operation / variable from this function and pass *that* to `sess.run()`

Comment: Hey did this answer help you @southdoor? You should close this question with your own answer / with this answer.